# Use Kotlin annotation class in Java class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, annotations, mockito

I'm writing new features in Kotlin but some stuff are already wrote in Java.

I'm writing tests in `Mockito(Kotlin)` but `Mockito` has problem with final class so I created:

```
annotation class Mockable {}
```

And added to `Gradle-build`:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-allopen'

allOpen {
    annotation('com.Mockable')
}
```

So using this annotation class I can mock `Kotlin` class.

How I can use this annotation in Java class ?

Comment: have you tried just using `@Mockable`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need it in *Java*. But regardless of this, there's an alternative method to use *Mockito* with *Kotlin*:

Create a file *src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker* with contents:

```
mock-maker-inline
```

This changes the mocking behavior to also support `final` classes like the *Kotlin* ones. For some *Java* classes I had to use `spy()` instead of `mock()` afterward though.

Comment: I saw this option but this is almost 3 times slower in performance

Answer (score 1):

> How I can use this annotation in Java class ?

You can't use this annotation in this way, because `kotlin-allopen` only works on Kotlin classes. In Java, just don't mark classes as `final`...

For that matter, in Kotlin it doesn't seem useful either if I understood you correctly: `kotlin-allopen` is used when the annotation is going to be processed in some way which requires creating subclasses of the annotated type, so you'd need to write `open` *as well as* annotation. Here, you can write `open` *instead of* `@Mockable`.